# Are Slime weapons affected by the Status Attack armor skill?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

Slime is considered a status, stacking it up causes an explosion at some critical point. Would you stack Slime faster if you had Status Attack or would the explosion do more damage? While we're on the topic, is the damage of the slime explosion affected by your weapon sharpness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damage of slime weapons is static and varies from monster to monster. It is unaffected by Status Attack Up, but is increased by Bombardier and Felyne Bombardier (from the kitchen).

Comment: I think the question was about _slime damage_ (i.e. the rate at which the SLM X number is added to eventually cause the explosion), but this answer only covers _damage from slime_ (i.e. the damage from the explosion).

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I have verified this by getting Status Up (both the armor skill and the Felyne version) and equipping the Demolition Axe. The skill is greyed out on the Hunter Status screen.